# How can i change the password reset URL in a Laravel Project?

Tags: laravel

In a Laravel project in the folder app/mail there is a file called WelcomeDogSchoolManager.php

In this file I can see the text that is being sent when a new user registers himself.

Within this file, I can see the following code:

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $passwordResetUrl])
    Registreren
@endcomponent
```

Unfortunately, the developer left a mistake in the $passwordResetUrl (leaving it at "https://login..{domain}.nl" instead of the required "https://login.{domain}.nl"

This causes all my users being unable to register (unless they manipulate the URL).

Where in the Laravel Project can I search for the option to change the $passwordResetUrl?

I have no working knowledge of Laravel and am basically just searching through all the files on the server using Filezilla, trying to figure it all out. I got to this point, but have no idea how to proceed further. And since I have 7.200 files left, I don't think I will find it quickly :)

Any tips are appreciated!

PS. I have also found this code. Is this helpful?

```
$this->passwordResetUrl = url(route('password.reset', [ 'token' => $token, 'email' => $this->user->email, ], false));
```

Is this helpful?

Full code for the file below

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Models\DogSchool;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

class WelcomeDogSchoolManager extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    public $subject = 'Welkom bij de Nederlandse Detectie Bond';

    public string $passwordResetUrl;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(public User $user, public DogSchool $dogSchool)
    {
        $token = Password::getRepository()->create($user);

        $this->passwordResetUrl = url(route('password.reset', [
            'token' => $token,
            'email' => $this->user->email,
        ], false));
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.welcome_dog_school_manager');
    }
}
```

Comment: look at route definition, all are seem correct, look where route defined.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
url(route('password.reset', [ 'token' => $token, 'email' => $this->user->email, ], false));
```

will generate the correct url provided your APP_URL is correct.

In your question, you repeated the same url for the desired and actual so its hard to say exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Adding to this, also check the env file to make sure APP_URL is set properly or the url helper won't work properly.

Comment: thought thats what I said

Comment: lol so you did, late night and morning eyes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The difference in the URL is the double point (login..{domain} instead of login.{domain}).

Very good suggestion to check the env file. Where is this usually located?

Comment: You are not forced to have a .env file. It depends how the project is deployed.  It is in the root of the project usually.  Make sure you list hidden files to see it.  After changing it, run php artisan config:clear

Comment: Oh wow, i totally missed your last comment and i am still doing this by hand. I checked the .env file and found out that the APP_URL is correct there:

APP_URL=https://login.detectiebond.nl

however, in the email it is: https://login..detectiebond.nl